# Run a task when UWP app is being deleted

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I need to do some process when the app is being deleted in order to remove all impacts that the app incurs to the system. My app stores some credentials in Windows-Hello-Secure storage (CredentialService) and these credentials only can be removed by the app that registered them.
Is there any way for doing that by running a task before uninstalling?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are no chance to remove the key at uninstallation. But, is this a real issue? If you use the Key Credential Manager for Windows Hello, only YOUR app can access the key. No one - except your app - can access for it.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, but the issue will be raised if the user wants to install the app again!

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. the app model should take of leaving the system in the right state back. it deletes the app store, it removes protocol and file handler. Do you have a specific  example for what you need to do this manually?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have mentioned what you need to know by improving the question.